# fortran 90 expected bounds specification during pointer assignment

Tags: pointers, fortran90, bounds, specifications

I am new to Fortran. I am writing a program in Fortran 90 to get non-zero elements of an array and put them into a new array using pointer function as following:

```
program prog
    implicit none
    integer, target :: a(5)
    integer :: i
    integer, pointer :: nz(:)


    a(1) = 1
    a(2) = 0
    a(3) = 0
    a(4) = 2
    a(5) = 3

    nz => non_zeros(a)
    do i=1, size(nz)
       write(*,*) nz(i)
    end do  

contains
function non_zeros(a)
    integer, target :: a(:) 
    integer, pointer:: non_zeros(:)
    integer :: n, i, j

    n = count(a .ne. 0)
    allocate(non_zeros(n))

    j = 0
    do i=1, m
        if (a(i) .ne. 0) then
            j = j + 1
            non_zeros(j) => a(i)
        end if
    end do  
end function non_zeros

end program prog
```

during compiling I got the error:

```
 non_zeros(j) => a(i)
 1
 Error: Expected bounds specification for 'non_zeros' at (1)
```

Can you please tell me what did I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

Update of my question: According to the explanation of High Performance Mark, I defined a derived type:

```
program prog
    implicit none
    integer, target :: a(5)
    type dt
        integer, pointer :: x
    end type
    type(dt), allocatable :: nz(:)


    a(1) = 1
    a(2) = 0
    a(3) = 0
    a(4) = 2
    a(5) = 3

    nz = non_zeros(a)

    contains

    function non_zeros(a)
        integer, target :: a(:) 
        type(dt), allocatable :: non_zeros(:)
        integer :: n, i, j

        n = count(a .ne. 0)
        allocate(non_zeros(n))

        j = 0
        do i=1, m
            if (a(i) .ne. 0) then
                j = j + 1
                non_zeros(j)%x => a(i)
            end if
        end do  

    end function non_zeros  
end program prog
```

Now program works and gives the desired results. However, I did not use pointer function in this case, since my function returns an allocatable array of pointers, not pointer to an array. Is there any way to use pointer function here? Thank you

Comment: I'm suspicious that you are trying to write C (or a similar language) in Fortran. The *array of derived-type with a pointer element* is the usual Fortran trick for producing something like an array of pointers, but it is not necessary for getting an array containing the non-zero elements of `a`.  What you are writing looks very contrived, unnatural to at least this Fortran programmer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark As I said, I am new to Fortran, I used to work on Python. That's why the program looks unnatural. Can you please as an expert in Fortran suggest me how to change my code, so that it will be natural Fortran program! Many thanks

Comment: I answered your question *I am writing a program in Fortran 90 to get non-zero elements of an array and put them into a new array* in my first response (below).  I see no need to use pointers for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the non-zero elements of `a` into a new array you could simply declare

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: non_zeros
```

and then populate that with the statement

```
non_zeros = pack(a,a/=0)
```

and avoid fiddling around with pointers entirely.  This relies on a feature introduced in the 2003 standard, but it is implemented by all (I think) the current crop of Fortran compilers on the market.

The code that you have written looks to me as if you want `nz` to be an array of pointers, with each element in `nz` pointing to a non-zero element of `a`.  If I'm right, you've misunderstood what a statement such as

```
integer, pointer :: nz(:)
```

declares.  It does not declare an array of pointers to integers, it declares a pointer to an array of integers.  When you write

```
non_zeros(j) => a(i)
```

you're making the mistake of trying to set an element of `non_zeros` to point to an element of `a`.

The error message is misleading here because the compiler interprets `non_zeros(j)` as a syntactically-incorrect *bounds-spec* or *bounds-remapping*, but the error is semantic, the compiler doesn't understand your misunderstanding of Fortran.

Comment: Thank you for your nice and helpful solution. I would follow it in writing my "real" program. I also read the topic about difference between pointer and allocatable arrays where experienced people recommend to use allocatable instead of pointer (in case allocatable arrays do the job). But here I want to practice with pointer and try to understand it more. So I am looking forward to see your second suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried to create a derived type as following `type dt integer, pointer :: x endtype` and then declare my results as `type(dt), allocatable :: nz(:)` Now program works and give the desired results. However, I did not use `pointer function` in this case, since my function returns an allocatable array of pointers, not pointer to an array. Is there any way to use 'pointer function` here?

Comment: Trying to figure out code in comments is too hard on my eyes.  Either edit your question or post a new one, or wait for someone with better visual acuity than I possess to answer your comment-question.

Comment: Sorry for my ugly comment, I have updated my question above. Please have a look and recommend. Thank you