# Assign pointer to non-target variables in a function

Tags: pointers, memory, fortran

In a previous question ([Assign pointer in derived type to target in the same type in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430363/assign-pointer-in-derived-type-to-target-in-the-same-type-in-fortran)) I was advised to always use `allocatable` over `pointer` if possible. However, in Fortran it is not allowed to declare a variable `allocatable, target` in a derived type. Therefore, I had to work around my problem in by assigning a `pointer` to a non-`target` variable in a function where I declare it `target`. It compiles, but is this save and the way to do this? It feels like a hack to me.

```
module mo_zoo
    implicit none
    type zoo
        integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: animals
        integer, dimension(:), pointer :: tigers
        integer, dimension(:), pointer :: ducks
    end type zoo

    save
        type(zoo) zoos

    contains
        subroutine assign_pointer(a_ptr, a, idx)
            integer, dimension(:), pointer, intent(inout) :: a_ptr
            integer, dimension(:,:), target, intent(in) :: a
            integer, intent(in) :: idx

            a_ptr => a(:, idx)
        end subroutine
end module mo_zoo

program test
    use mo_zoo
    implicit none

    allocate(zoos%animals(10,2))
    call assign_pointer(zoos%tigers, zoos%animals, 1)
    call assign_pointer(zoos%ducks, zoos%animals, 2)
end program test
```

Comment: The need for `pointer`s is extremely rare in Fortran. One could achieve almost all goals with `source`d `allocatable`s. But you may have good reasons for pointer usage that I do not know. With pointers in your code, the onus is on you to ensure all pointers are `nullify()`ed before going out of scope. Other than that, it looks fine at a glance (+ there is no need for the keyword `dimension` like `real, allocatable :: a(:)` + all module objects have `save` attribute automatically, so no need for the `save` attribute of `type(zoo) zoos`).

Comment: @King, but is there a way to declare my `animals` variable `allocatable, target` without having to give up the `type`? I use pointers mainly as shortcuts to permit a simpler syntax.

Comment: `zoos%animals` doesn't have the target attribute, so the pointer association statuses of `zoos%tigers` and `zoos%ducks` are undefined after the calls to `assign_pointer`. That's fine as long as you don't do anything which requires the pointer association statuses to be defined.

Comment: @Chiel If syntax the only reason, then why not use the `associate` construct with which you won't even need to declare pointers? `associate(tigers => zoos%animals(:,1), ducks => zoos%animals(:,2)); ...; end associate`. The compiler effectively creates the desired pointers which will be nullified automatically upon `end`ing `associate`.

Comment: @King. I did not know `associate`. This looks really helpful for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @King. Is there a way to have an associate at the module scope?

Comment: An associate construct is an executable construct, so can appear only where executable statements may appear. That excludes module scope.